# PySpark: iterate inside small groups in DataFrame

Tags: python, pyspark, grouping, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to understand how can I do operations inside small groups in a PySpark DataFrame. Suppose I have DF with the following schema:

```
root
|-- first_id: string (nullable = true)
|-- second_id_struct: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- s_id: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- s_id_2: int (nullable = true)
|-- depth_from: float (nullable = true)
|-- depth_to: float (nullable = true)
|-- total_depth: float (nullable = true)
```

So data might look something like this:

I would like to:

1. group data by first_id
2. inside each group, order it by s_id_2 in ascending order
3. append extra column `layer` to either struct or root DataFrame that would indicate order of this `s_id_2` in a group.

For example:

```
first_id | second_id | second_id_order 
---------| --------- | ---------------
      A1 |   [B, 10] | 1  
---------| --------- | ---------------
      A1 |   [B, 14] | 2
---------| --------- | ---------------
      A1 |   [B, 22] | 3
---------| --------- | ---------------
      A5 |    [A, 1] | 1
---------| --------- | ---------------
      A5 |    [A, 7] | 2
---------| --------- | ---------------
      A7 |      null | 1
---------| --------- | ---------------
```

Once grouped each `first_id` will have at most 4 `second_id_struct`. How do I approach those kind of problems?

I am particularly interested in how to make iterative operations inside small groups (1-40 rows) of DataFrames in general, where order of columns inside a group matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a DataFrame

```
d = [{'first_id': 'A1', 'second_id': ['B',10]}, {'first_id': 'A1', 'second_id': ['B',14]},{'first_id': 'A1', 'second_id': ['B',22]},{'first_id': 'A5', 'second_id': ['A',1]},{'first_id': 'A5', 'second_id': ['A',7]}]

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(d)
```

And you can see the structure

```
df.printSchema()

|-- first_id: string (nullable = true)
|-- second_id: array (nullable = true)
|........|-- element: string (containsNull = true)

df.show()
+--------+----------+
|first_id|second_id |
+--------+----------+
|      A1|   [B, 10]|
|      A1|   [B, 14]|
|      A1|   [B, 22]|
|      A5|    [A, 1]|
|      A5|    [A, 7]|
+--------+----------+
```

Then you can use **dense_rank** and **Window** function to show the order in the subgroup. It is as same as over partition in SQL.

The introduction of window function: [Introducing Window Functions in Spark SQL](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html)

Code here:

```
# setting a window spec
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy('first_id').orderBy(df.second_id[1])
# apply dense_rank to the window spec
df.select(df.first_id, df.second_id, dense_rank().over(windowSpec).alias("second_id_order")).show()
```

Result:

```
+--------+---------+---------------+
|first_id|second_id|second_id_order|
+--------+---------+---------------+
|      A1|  [B, 10]|              1|
|      A1|  [B, 14]|              2|
|      A1|  [B, 22]|              3|
|      A5|   [A, 1]|              1|
|      A5|   [A, 7]|              2|
+--------+---------+---------------+
```